# Fastest way(performance wise) to add line items dynamically in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am developing a webform which needs to have `LineItems`  ie. some textboxes, calendar,dropdowns etc in a row which can be added dynamically on button click.

An example from my previous works:

[image]

I developed this using a GridView and maintained the state of controls using `DataTable` and `ViewState` on `Click to Add` link button.

The problem with this approach is that it becomes very slow as number of controls increase.

What are other alternatives? I know I can use repeater but I am not sure how much difference is that gonna make? I would not want to explore new way if the performance improvement is like 5%.

I can use jquery and html client side elements but then maintaing state would be a headace (I cant avoid postbacks , there are already many drop downs and fileuploads on the same form that cause postback ). 
OR if there is an easy way to maintian the state of HTML elements?

This is not opinion based question since , performance and be percieved and measured.

Comment: Add paging to minimize the number of rows / controls

Answer (score 0):

I can think of several options:

- Implement paging/limiting so customers can only see *N* rows at a time
- Implement master-slave views: split one large table in two. Master table only lists items and slave table only show details for the currently selected row
- Search for other jquery plugins, perhaps there are newer/faster plugins available (sorry couldn't offer any better alternatives, but they might exist)
- You may find good answers at UX design web-site, such as [How To Display Too Much Data](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/1459), [tables with lots of columns](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/tables-with-lots-of-columns?lq=1), [Best way to display more table columns and rows than I have room for?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22441/best-way-to-display-more-table-columns-and-rows-than-i-have-room-for?lq=1)

Comment: Talking of Jquery plug ins take a look at this:http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Dynamic-Data-Grid-Plugin-appendGrid/
How brillant is this? But I cant use it , because there are server controls on the form and they cause postback! Only if there was an easy way to maintain state of clientside controls.